# cURL não funciona com artisan serve?

Tags: laravel, libcurl, artisan

Atualmente meu amigo está tendo os mesmos problemas que tive ao tentar utilizar o cURL para consumir a API, servindo a aplicação com **php artisan serve**.

Existe alguma limitação que não permita o uso do cURL com o artisan serve? Pois, apesar da extensão estar habilitada no php.ini, o script tem um longo tempo de execução, até que é cancelado por timeout e, por fim, causa problemas.

Já quando utilizo algum outro servidor HTTP não tenho esse problema, somente com o artisan serve.

A pergunta é somente para conhecimento, pois tenho procurado sobre isso e não encontrei nada relacionado até o momento.

Comment: Usar cURL para consumir sua API servida pelo Laravel ou usar o cURL dentro da sua API servida pelo Laravel para consumir outras APIs quaisquer?

Comment: @Costamilam, Meu amigo está tentando consumir, no controller da página, a API que criou na mesma aplicação. Mas, por experiência pessoal, já tive problemas ao tentar consumir outras APIs e não ter sucesso por causa do artisan serve.